# Windows Library - Playing Musical Notes

Tags: .net, winapi

Is there an up-to-date Windows Library which allows the playing of individual musical notes?

Even just a wrapper on top of Beep, would suffice, though I don't know if that would be supported on all version of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MIDI.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910248.aspx) is a native code sample.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx) is a .Net wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an exact match for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1.aspx